# Resolving this probability paradox

Tags: probability

We toss a fair coin 100 times. We get 100 heads in a row.

Now we toss this coin one more time. Two things, each individually, make sense to me:

- The probability of heads coming up again is 1/2 (since the coin is fair).
- The probability of heads coming up 101 times in a row is $1/2^{101} = 3.944\times 10^{-31}$.

Each of these makes perfect sense.

Yet if I look at the two together, my head swims. Do you see the same paradox I'm seeing? How do I resolve it?

Comment: You don't resolve it because there is no paradox. The probabilities are different in the two assertions because they refer to completely different events

Comment: Probabilities are about future events. If you know about past events, they add conditions to the probability.

Comment: You are committing the classic **Gambler's Fallacy** ([link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy#An_example:_coin-tossing)).

Comment: The chances of being on a plane onto which someone has brought a bomb are small, but significant. So you should always bring a bomb onto the plane yourself, because the chances of being on a plane with *two* bombs are negligible.

Comment: @MJD I **urge** you to post this as an answer! :-)

Comment: Think of it as if you get 100 heads in a row, you already did something with ridiculously low probability, so it shouldn't be too surprising tossing 101 has such a low prob. Do you see the paradox disappear?

Comment: Unless you somehow managed to convince yourself beforehand that the coin was fair with $99.999999\ldots\%$ probability, you should be pretty convinced by now that it's *not*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocam's razor  would suggest that such a coin is not fair. But leaving this aside we can say the following:

(a) After 100 hundred tosses with whatever outcome, by definition of a "fair coin" the probability that the next toss is heads is ${1\over2}$.

(b) Before the start of the experiment each of the $2^{100}$ possible outcomes of the first $100$ tosses, be it $100$ heads or the parity of the first $100$ decimal places of $\pi$, has the same probability $2^{-100}$. When these tosses have all been performed their outcome is known, and we can no longer use the a-priori probability of the already observed outcome in speculations about the probability of some future event encompassing this already observed outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is realizing that the events (tossing the coins) are *independent* from one another. That is, whatever you've done with the coin in the past will have absolutely nothing to do with what occurs in the future. So the resolution to this supposed paradox is that it will still come up heads on your 101st toss with a 50% chance.

However, if you were to ask *before you started tossing the coin* this question: "How likely is it that the coin will land on heads 101 times in a row?" That's where the calculation comes in of $$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{101} \approx 3.9443045 * 10^{-31}$$

Answer (score 1):

Flipping such a coin has no relation to previous outcomes. Therefore, truly, regardless of what the previous flips were, the odds of heads is 1/2.

However, taken *as a whole*, flipping a fair coin 101 times and getting 101 heads is extremely unlikely $(0.5)^{101}$.

There is no paradox, just a question of what *event* you are considering -- a single flip, or 101 flips.

In other words, a fair coin has no memory.